# To cheers of "well played" - meaning

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/pro-russian-militants-attack-police-hq-ukraines-odessa-141824310.html

> In a bid to calm the crowd, police freed one of the detained pro-Russians, who emerged to **cheers of "well played"** from the protesters.

How do you understand that phrase in bold?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a possible mistranslation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it is just an inaccurate translation. The protesters were shouting "Молодец!". This can be sometimes translated as "well played", but obviously not in this situation. It will be more appropriate to simply state that the crowd was cheering him, or at least translate it as "Well done!". The word "Молодец" simply indicates that you support and praise a man for what he's doing or has done.

Answer (score 0):

It means you gave it a shot, well done, good try...:

**молодец**! [молоде́ц] {interj.} well done! {interj.}

**молодец!** [молоде́ц] {interj.} ataboy! {interj.}

Когда у них будут свои дети, в 2050-м году я надеюсь они посмотрят на дедушку и скажут "Слушай, ты - **молодец**. When they have their kids, 2050, they'd better look back at Grandpa and say, "Hey, you gave it a good shot.

Хороший робот, **молодец**. Good robot, that's good.

en.bab.la/dictionary/russian-english/молодец